# Is there any implementation of Transparent Distributed Queries over a graph database?

Tags: graph, nosql, distributed, p2p

- I'm designing a P2P application in which every peer have a partial graph.
- Some nodes in the partial graph can be proxy nodes which contain contact information for another peer.
- That peer's partial graph includes that proxy node (and potentially other parts of the complete graph).

Any chance you can give me some direction on how to implement queries over this graph?

From what I've found in the web there is no real implementation that enable easy querying.
infogrid sounds like it might help, but it doesn't seem easy to use or stable.
hypergraphDB has a P2P API, but it doesn't seem all that related to the query process.

Comment: I didn't find a suitable solution so I made my own graph framework, it is called GraphPack and its source code is at code.google.com/p/graphpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made my own **decentralized graph database**, called [*GraphPack*](https://github.com/amitport/graphpack).

Comment: Visited https://code.google.com/archive/p/graphpack/ but seems there's no downloads available or source code

Comment: The project was migrated to github. I've updated the link. @sarah.ferguson

Answer (score 0):

HypergraphDB does what you want, check out [this p2p-intro](http://www.hypergraphdb.org/learn?page=CommunicationImplementation&project=hypergraphdb) and [this p2p-related Tutorial](http://www.hypergraphdb.org/learn?page=PeerToPeerTutorial&project=hypergraphdb). It's quite a nice and powerful thing. For instance, it allows you to build a distributed finite state machine.
Querying is not part of the P2P API. The latter mainly defines how peers (almost literally) "talk" to each other and communicate about their "interests".
Given a HyperGraphPeer p1, you can access that peer's Hypergraph by p1.getGraph on which you can call i.e. find(yourHGQueryCondition).
Basically you can broadcast a message to all peers in a peer group, and the messageHandler of the proxy peer can be configured to answer accordingly.
HyperGraphDB P2P currently relies on XMPP, but you can easily plugin another by implementing PeerInterface. I'm considering to do so sometime in the next months using redis or akka or hazelcast..

Comment: Hey, after giving it a try I found it complicated to implement distributed queries using hypergraphDB. I wanted something that can be as expressive as using a graph query language like gremlin or chyper. Currently I've made my own prototype of such a system (with a query langugae that is similar to chyper) and I will soon publish it (free and open source)